# Difference between print and putStrLn in Haskell

Tags: haskell, printing, ghc

I am confused. I tried to use `print`, but I know people apply `putStrLn`. What are the real differences between them?

```
print $ function 
putStrLn $ function
```

Comment: `print = putStrLn . show`

Comment: Have you tried running `print 3`, `putStrLn 3`, `print "three"`, `putStrLn "three"` in ghci?  This is really a question that can be answered by a bit of experimentation.

Comment: Unasked plug: defining `proom = putStrLn . groom` (from the `groom` package) increases AST readability a lot. No more hunting for "where does the next element start".

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The function `putStrLn` takes a `String` and displays it to the screen, followed by a newline character (**put** a **Str**ing followed by a new **L**i**n**e).

Because it only works with `String`s, a common idiom is to take any object, convert it to a `String`, and then apply `putStrLn` to display it. The generic way to convert an object to a `String` is with the `show` function, so your code would end up with a lot of

```
putStrLn (show 1)
putStrLn (show [1, 2, 3])
putStrLn (show (Just 42))
```

Once you notice that, it's not a very big stretch to define a function that converts to a `String` and displays the string in one step

```
print x = putStrLn (show x)
```

which is exactly what the `print` function is.

Comment: `putStrLn` can show non ASCII characters like "я" whereas `print` cannot. I don't really know why though. Try `putStrLn "я"` vs `print "я"`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai It's for the reason I give in the answer. The `print` function calls `putStrLn` on the output of `show`, and the `show` functions converts strings to their unicode representation in order to display them. The unicode point for 'я' (Cyrillic letter "ya") is U+044F, or 1103 in decimal, which is why `show "я"` outputs  `"\"\\1103\""` - this is what you would have to type in ghci to get the string composed of the seven characters `"\1103"` (try it!)

Comment: Doesn't this mean it would better to use `putStrLn` when working with text in general?

Comment: If you have a `String` that you want to print to the screen, you should use `putStrLn`. If you have something *other than* a `String` that you want to print, you should use `print`. Look at the types! `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` and `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`.

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused. Literally the only difference between `putStrLn` and `print` is that `print` calls `show` on its input first. Any difference between the result is because you have called `show` on the input in one case, and not in the other. So when choosing which one to use, ask yourself - do I want to call `show` on the input or not? If the input is a `String` then you almost certainly *do not* want to call `show` on it first.