# Haskell function that takes input as a String and returns same sequence of characters in reverse order

Tags: haskell

The issue is, I am doing:

`reverse ("Hello how are you")` 
and getting output as: `"uoy era woh olleh"` 
but the expected output is: `uoy era woh olleh`

Not sure how to remove quotes(") from the above string.

Comment: They aren't actually there, they're part of the representation of any string.

Comment: Do you mean it is converting the upper case "H" into lower case as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "doing"? Running the expression in ghci?

Comment: What is the difference between what you get and what you expect?

Comment: You might find [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316859/2751851) somewhat relevant.

Comment: The quotes are there for essentially the same reason that you write `reverse ("Hello how are you")` and not `reverse (Hello how are you)`.

Comment: Those quotes are *not* part of the string. There is a difference between the *content* of a string, and its *representation*.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're referring to this:

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghci
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghc/ghci.conf
Prelude> reverse "Hello how are you"
"uoy era woh olleH"
```

...when actually you would like to have the reply without any quotes around it. Well, GHCi passes all evaluation results through [`print`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print), which in turn uses the [`Show` typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show) to transform any value into a string – notably, *a string that's valid Haskell source code*, and could as such be used to recreate the value. (That's extremely useful in prototyping, and it's not limited to strings but can also handle all sorts of other types.)

Now, `"uoy era woh olleH"` clearly is valid Haskell source code

```
Prelude> "uoy era woh olleH"
"uoy era woh olleH"
```

but without the quotes it wouldn't be:

```
Prelude> uoy era woh olleH

<interactive>:3:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: uoy :: t0 -> t1 -> t2 -> t

<interactive>:3:5: error: Variable not in scope: era

<interactive>:3:9: error: Variable not in scope: woh

<interactive>:3:13: error: Variable not in scope: olleH
```

that's why GHCi does this. But if you don't want to use the reply as Haskell code, then you also don't need the `show` wrapper. To just print *the raw content of strings*, you'll need to explicitly use the IO action whose purpose this is: [`putStrLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn)

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ reverse "Hello how are you"
uoy era woh olleH
```

<sup>(If you don't know what `$` is yet: read it as a shorthand notation for `putStrLn (reverse "Hello how are you")`.)</sup>